# How to make a ghost image move beyond the tabbed pane dialog during drag and drop?

Tags: java, swing, awt

I have a `JDialog` with a `JPanel` that contains a tabbed Pane.  Using drag and drop, I would like the ghost image to move beyond the `JDialog`.  The cursor can move all over the screen, so how can I make the ghost image follow it?

```
package PlannerManager;

import GUIUtils;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable;
import java.awt.dnd.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.net.URL;

public class DnDTabbedPane extends JTabbedPane
{
    private int    LINEWIDTH  = 3;
    private String NAME       = "TabTransferData";
    private DataFlavor FLAVOR = new DataFlavor(DataFlavor.
                              javaJVMLocalObjectMimeType, NAME);

    private GhostClassPane glassPaneGhost  = new GhostClassPane();
    private boolean        isDrawRect      = false;
    private Rectangle2D    lineRect        = new Rectangle2D.Double();
    private Color          lineColor       = new Color(0, 100, 255);
    private TabAcceptor    acceptor        = null;
    private ImageIcon      iconImageCancel = null;
    private Container      myParent        = null;

    protected DetailsTabbedPaneDialog tabbedDetailsDlg = null;

    // constructor
    public DnDTabbedPane(Container parentCont, String,
                                                iconCancelWithPath,
                         final Plans plans, final GUIUtils guiUtils,
                         final String name)
    {
        super();
        myParent = parentCont;

        final DragSourceListener dsl = new DragSourceListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void dragEnter(DragSourceDragEvent e)
            {
                e.getDragSourceContext().setCursor(
                                     new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
            }

            @Override
            public void dragExit(DragSourceEvent e)
            {
                e.getDragSourceContext().setCursor(
                                      new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
                lineRect.setRect(0, 0, 0, 0);
                isDrawRect = false;
                glassPaneGhost.setPoint(new Point(-1000, -1000));
                glassPaneGhost.repaint();
            }

            @Override
            public void dragOver(DragSourceDragEvent e)
            {
                System.out.println("drag exit");
                TabTransferData data = getTabTransferData(e);
                if (data == null)
                {
                    e.getDragSourceContext().setCursor(
                                       new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void dragDropEnd(DragSourceDropEvent e)
            {
                isDrawRect = false;
                lineRect.setRect(0, 0, 0, 0);
                glassPaneGhost.setVisible(false);
                glassPaneGhost.setImage(null);

                // If drop failed, create new JDialog with JTabbedPane
                if (!e.getDropSuccess())
                {
                    Point dropLocation = e.getLocation();

                    // Create new JDialog with JTabbedPane
                    tabbedDetailsDlg = new DetailsTabbedPaneDialog(
                            myParent, plans, guiUtils, name,
                            dropLocation.x, dropLocation.y, false);

                    // Transfer the tab to the new JTabbedPane
                    tabbedDetailsDlg.tabbedPane.convertTab(
                            getTabTransferData(e),
                            getTargetTabIndex(dropLocation));
                }

                if (1 > getTabCount())
                {
                    ((JDialog) myParent).dispose();
                }
            }

            public void dropActionChanged(DragSourceDragEvent e)
            {
            }
        };

        final DragGestureListener dgl = new DragGestureListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void dragGestureRecognized(DragGestureEvent e)
            {
                Point tabPt = e.getDragOrigin();
                int dragTabIndex = indexAtLocation(tabPt.x, tabPt.y);
                if (0 <= dragTabIndex)
                {
                    initGlassPane(e.getComponent(), e.getDragOrigin(), 
                                                        dragTabIndex);
                    try
                    {
                        e.startDrag(DragSource.DefaultMoveDrop,
                                new TabTransferable(dragTabIndex), dsl);
                    }
                    catch (InvalidDnDOperationException ex)
                    {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        new DropTarget(this, DnDConstants.ACTION_MOVE,
                new CDropTargetListener(), true);
        new DragSource().createDefaultDragGestureRecognizer(this,
                     DnDConstants.ACTION_MOVE, dgl);
        acceptor = new TabAcceptor()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean isDropAcceptable(DnDTabbedPane component, 
                                                           int index)
            {
                return true;
            }
        };

        URL iconURL = 
            getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(iconCancelWithPath);
        if (null != iconURL)
        {
            iconImageCancel = new ImageIcon(iconURL);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void addTab(String title, final Component component)
    {
        JLabel label = new JLabel(title);
        label.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 12));
        JPanel tab = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        tab.setOpaque(false);
        tab.add(label, BorderLayout.WEST);
        JButton buttonCancel = new JButton(iconImageCancel);
        if (null != iconImageCancel)
        {
            tab.add(buttonCancel, BorderLayout.EAST);
        }
        super.addTab(title, component);
        int idx = indexOfComponent(component);
        setTabComponentAt(idx, tab);
        setSelectedIndex(getTabCount() - 1);
        buttonCancel.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                // See if the dialog is empty
                if (1 >= getTabCount())
                {
                    ((JDialog) myParent).dispose();
                }
                else
                {
                    remove(component);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private TabTransferData getTabTransferData(DropTargetDropEvent 
                                                       event)
    {
        try
        {
            return (TabTransferData) 
                        event.getTransferable().getTransferData(FLAVOR);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private TabTransferData getTabTransferData(DropTargetDragEvent
                                                            event)
    {
        try
        {
            return (TabTransferData) 
                        event.getTransferable().getTransferData(FLAVOR);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }


    private TabTransferData getTabTransferData(DragSourceDropEvent 
                                                                  event)
    {
        try
        {
            return (TabTransferData) event.getDragSourceContext()
                    .getTransferable().getTransferData(FLAVOR);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }


    private TabTransferData getTabTransferData(DragSourceDragEvent
                                                        event)
    {
        try
        {
            return (TabTransferData) event.getDragSourceContext()
                    .getTransferable().getTransferData(FLAVOR);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }


    class TabTransferable implements Transferable
    {
        private TabTransferData data = null;

        public TabTransferable(int tabIndex)
        {
            data = new TabTransferData(DnDTabbedPane.this, tabIndex);
        }

        public Object getTransferData(DataFlavor flavor)
        {
            return data;
        }

        public DataFlavor[] getTransferDataFlavors()
        {
            DataFlavor[] flavors = new DataFlavor[1];
            flavors[0] = FLAVOR;
            return flavors;
        }

        public boolean isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor flavor)
        {
            return (flavor.getHumanPresentableName().equals(NAME));
        }
    }

    class TabTransferData
    {
        private DnDTabbedPane tabbedPane = null;
        private int           tabIndex   = -1;

        public TabTransferData(DnDTabbedPane tabbedPane_in, int 
                                                           tabIndex_in)
        {
            tabbedPane = tabbedPane_in;
            tabIndex   = tabIndex_in;
        }

        public DnDTabbedPane getTabbedPane()
        {
            return tabbedPane;
        }

        public int getTabIndex()
        {
            return tabIndex;
        }
    }

    private Point buildGhostLocation(Point pointLocation)
    {
        return SwingUtilities.convertPoint(this, new 
                                             Point(pointLocation),
                glassPaneGhost);
    }

    class CDropTargetListener implements DropTargetListener
    {
        public void dragEnter(DropTargetDragEvent e)
        {
            e.acceptDrag(e.getDropAction());
        }

        public void dragExit(DropTargetEvent e)
        {
            isDrawRect = false;
        }

        public void dropActionChanged(DropTargetDragEvent e)
        {
        }

        public void dragOver(final DropTargetDragEvent e)
        {
            repaint();             
            glassPaneGhost.setPoint(buildGhostLocation(
                                                e.getLocation()));
            glassPaneGhost.repaint();
        }

        @Override
        public void drop(DropTargetDropEvent e)
        {
            if (isDropAcceptable(e))
            {
                convertTab(getTabTransferData(e),
                           getTargetTabIndex(e.getLocation()));
                e.dropComplete(true);
            }
            else
            {
                e.dropComplete(false);
            }

            isDrawRect = false;
            repaint();
        }

        public boolean isDropAcceptable(DropTargetDropEvent e)
        {
            boolean bRet = false;

            Transferable transferable = e.getTransferable();
            if (null != transferable)
            {
                DataFlavor[] flavor = e.getCurrentDataFlavors();
                if (transferable.isDataFlavorSupported(flavor[0]))
                {
                    TabTransferData data = getTabTransferData(e);

                    if (null != data)
                    {
                        if (DnDTabbedPane.this == data.getTabbedPane())
                        {
                            bRet = (data.getTabIndex() >= 0);
                        }
                        else if (acceptor != null)
                        {
                            bRet = acceptor.
                                   isDropAcceptable(
                                       data.getTabbedPane(),
                                       data.getTabIndex());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return bRet;
        }
    }

    private int getTargetTabIndex(Point point)
    {
        int idx = 0;
        boolean isTopOrBottom = getTabPlacement() == JTabbedPane.Top
                                                   ||
                                getTabPlacement() == JTabbedPane.BOTTOM;

        if (0 != getTabCount())
        {
            boolean bFound = false;
            for (int i = 0; (i < getTabCount()) && (!bFound); i++)
            {
                Rectangle rect = getBoundsAt(i);
                if (isTopOrBottom)
                {
                    rect.setRect(rect.x - rect.width / 2, rect.y, 
                                              rect.width, rect.height);
                }
                else
                {
                    rect.setRect(rect.x, rect.y - rect.height / 2, 
                                          rect.width, rect.height);
                }
                if (rect.contains(point))
                {
                    bFound = true;
                    idx = i;
                }
            }
            if (!bFound)
            {
                Rectangle rect = getBoundsAt(getTabCount() - 1);

                if (isTopOrBottom)
                {
                    int x = rect.x + rect.width / 2;
                    rect.setRect(x, rect.y, getWidth() - x, 
                                                  rect.height);
                }
                else
                {
                    int y = rect.y + rect.height / 2;
                    rect.setRect(rect.x, y, rect.width, getHeight() - 
                                                                   y);
                }

                idx = (rect.contains(point) ? getTabCount() : -1);
            }
        }
        return idx;
    }


    private void convertTab(TabTransferData sourceTab, int targetIndex)
    {
        DnDTabbedPane source = sourceTab.getTabbedPane();
        int sourceIndex = sourceTab.getTabIndex();
        if (sourceIndex >= 0)
        {
            Component sourceComp = source.getComponentAt(sourceIndex);
            String sourceTitle = source.getTitleAt(sourceIndex);
            Component sourceTabComp = 
                                  source.getTabComponentAt(sourceIndex);

            if (this != source)
            {
                // Not same tab plane
                // Remove the source from the other tabbed plane
                source.remove(sourceIndex);
                if (targetIndex == getTabCount())
                {
                    // Add the source tab to the end
                    addTab(sourceTitle, sourceComp);
                    setTabComponentAt(getTabCount() - 1, sourceTabComp);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (targetIndex < 0)
                    {
                        targetIndex = 0;
                    }
                    // Insert at the beginning
                    insertTab(sourceTitle, null, sourceComp, null, 
                                                        targetIndex);
                    setTabComponentAt(targetIndex, sourceTabComp);
                }
                setSelectedComponent(sourceComp);
            }
            else
            {
                // Same tab plane
                if (targetIndex >= 0 && sourceIndex != targetIndex)
                {
                    source.remove(sourceIndex);
                    if (targetIndex == getTabCount())
                    {
                        addTab(sourceTitle, sourceComp);
                        setTabComponentAt(getTabCount() - 1, 
                                                       sourceTabComp);
                        setSelectedIndex(getTabCount() - 1);
                    }
                    else if (sourceIndex > targetIndex)
                    {
                        insertTab(sourceTitle, null, sourceComp, null, 
                                                       targetIndex);
                        setTabComponentAt(targetIndex, sourceTabComp);
                        setSelectedIndex(targetIndex);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        insertTab(sourceTitle, null, sourceComp, null, 
                                                       targetIndex - 1);
                        setTabComponentAt(targetIndex - 1, 
                                                        sourceTabComp);
                        setSelectedIndex(targetIndex - 1);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void initGlassPane(Component component, Point tabPt, int 
                                                         tabIndex)
    {
        getRootPane().setGlassPane(glassPaneGhost);
        Rectangle rect = getBoundsAt(tabIndex);
        BufferedImage image = 
                   new BufferedImage(component.getWidth(),
                                     component.getHeight(), 
                                     BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        component.paint(image.getGraphics());
        image = image.getSubimage(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, 
                                                        rect.height);
        glassPaneGhost.setImage(image);
        glassPaneGhost.setPoint(buildGhostLocation(tabPt));
        glassPaneGhost.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (isDrawRect)
        {
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2.setPaint(lineColor);
            g2.fill(lineRect);
        }
    }

    public interface TabAcceptor
    {
        boolean isDropAcceptable(DnDTabbedPane component, int index);
    }

    class GhostClassPane extends JPanel
    {
        private Point location = new Point(0, 0);
        private BufferedImage draggingGhost = null;
        private AlphaComposite composite;

        public GhostClassPane()
        {
            setOpaque(false);
            composite = AlphaComposite.getInstance(
                                     AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 0.5f);
        }

        public void setImage(BufferedImage draggingGhost_in)
        {
            draggingGhost = draggingGhost_in;
        }

        public void setPoint(Point location_in)
        {
            location = location_in;
        }

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
        {
            if (null != draggingGhost)
            {
                Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
                g2.setComposite(composite);

                g2.drawImage(draggingGhost, (int) location.getX(),
                        (int) location.getY(), null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use MouseInfo to locate the mouse on the screen.

This is the code to capture the mouse location as it moves across the screen with the ghost image attached.

```
class MickeyOnTheMove extends Thread
{
    private   Boolean          done           = false;
    private   MickeyOnTheMove  mickey         = null;
    private   Point            currentPoint   = null;
    private   GhostDialog      dlgGhost       = null;
    private   Point            prevPoint      = null;
    private   Point            ghostPoint     = null;


    public MickeyOnTheMove(Image ghostImage)
    {
        prevPoint    = new Point(MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation());
        currentPoint = new Point(MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation());
        ghostPoint   = new Point((int)currentPoint.getX() + 10,
                                 (int)currentPoint.getY() + 10);

        dlgGhost = new GhostDialog(ghostImage);
        dlgGhost.setLocation(ghostPoint);
        dlgGhost.setVisible(true);
        dlgGhost.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        dlgGhost.toFront();
    }


    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            done = false;

            while (!done)
            {
                currentPoint = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
                if ((prevPoint.getX() != currentPoint.getX()) ||
                        (prevPoint.getY() != currentPoint.getY()))
                {
                    ghostPoint = new Point((int)currentPoint.getX() + 10,
                            (int)currentPoint.getY() + 10);
                    if (null != dlgGhost)
                    {
                        dlgGhost.setLocation(ghostPoint);
                        dlgGhost.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
                        dlgGhost.toFront();
                    }

                    prevPoint = currentPoint;

                    Thread.sleep(0);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            done = true;
        }
    }


    void setContextCursor(DragSourceContext context, int cursorType)
    {
        context.setCursor(new Cursor(cursorType));
    }


    public void allDone()
    {
        done = true;

        if (null != dlgGhost)
        {
            dlgGhost.setVisible(false);
            dlgGhost.dispose();
            dlgGhost = null;
        }

        if (null != mickey)
        {
            mickey.interrupt();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I cannot provide you with actual code since I just don't have the time to do so, but I could give you a hint into the right direction how it COULD be done:

You want a "ghost picture" to follow the mouse whenever you hover out of the droppane as I understand you right.

You can go and create a simple JFrame with no decoration
`JFrame.getRootPane().setWindowDecorationStyle(JRootPane.NONE);` 
and then use a BufferedImage of the image you want to display, resize it to let's say 120x120 and drop it onto the frame.

Now you have to stick `JFrame.setBounds(x,y,w,h)` to your mouse cursor.

IIRC you can achieve this by getting the mouse position with the help of the Robot class. Then use a mouselistener, and as long as mouse1 is pressed, keep following the cursor with this "ghost picture". If the mousebutton is getting released, check weather it is over the drop pane or not and set

```
JFrame.setVisible(false);
```

I hope I could help you with your problem, sorry for not commiting any actual code for you but as I said my time is rare these days, just wanted to help the community out if I could.

Comment: @clockwOrk what does the mouse listener get added to?  I need to be able to drag across the entire screen.

Comment: Hi there, I think you would want to add a Robot from java.awt.Robot. It can give you the absolute position of the mouse on the screen